# Overlay a shapfile on a (raster) filledContour plot

Tags: r, shiny, polygon, raster, contour

I have a simple raster, that running through the filledContour function in the raster package, to give a filled contour plot.

I am trying to overlay the outline of a polygon over the top of this filled contour plot but having trouble.

reading the notes in filled.contour - adding lines to a filled contour plot has to be done in the plot.axis section, but not having any luck.

So far i have something like this:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
test_raster <- raster("test_raster.grd")
test_Shapefile <- readOGR("test_shapefile.shp")
test_filled_contour <- filledContour(test, maxpixels=100000,  plot.axes = {
  axis(1)
  axis(2)
  map(test_Shapefile, add=T)             
})
```

Both the raster and shapefile use the same coordinate system.

Any help welcome, i can provide the data if needed.

Comment: Try the `tmap` package.  The slide I link here shows how you can overlay a vector on a raster, but you may need to use `tm_raster()` instead of `tm_rgb()` (see previous slides for more details on that).  You may also need to convert your `test_Shapefile` sp object to an sf object using `st_as_sf()`.  If you post the data, we can try it out.  https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.zevross.com/workshops/spatial/slides/html/3-mapping.html#72

Comment: What would be the best way to post the data @EugeneChong

Comment: Can you make a smaller sample of it and post them in the question using the output from `dput()`?

Comment: @EugeneChong using dput() on the shapefile and raster gives a long output, i have uploaded the files to Gofile - heres the link https://gofile.io/?c=jYkWJB i can put them in a dropbox if you prefer

Comment: I get an error from that.  Dropbox may be better.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p8h0jjmf1oj843o/AACjxKFcnkMw4ubjO_BeZaKFa?dl=0

Here is the drop box @EugeneChong

Comment: thanks for posting the data. I gave it a shot but had trouble with using `plot.axes` with a polygon like you did. The closest I got was `library(tmap);
tm_shape(test_raster) + tm_raster(style = "cont", interpolate = T) +
  tm_shape(test_Shapefile) + tm_borders()`. It overlays the polygons and interpolates the raster values but lacks the contour lines in your original plot. Hope that is of at least some help. Best of luck with your project.